# Exporting data to Excel, Docs and PDF (Dotnet Core 2.x)

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-poi, reporting, openxml

I have ongoing project that need to export data into excel, docs and pdf.
We need to import it into predefined file (such have header and footer on each page).

Also for the (Ms) Docs, I need to be able to open docs and mail merge into the docs, and also could convert to pdf afterthat.

I found some people recommend between using NPOI and OpenXML for this one. But I am overwhelmed with the information on the internet. Which one between NPOI or OpenXML that suits for this job ? I am open to other library as well.
I prefer to use one that easier to use.

Our project is using Dotnet Core 2.1x and Angular 6 at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

For Excel exports I can recommend to use time-proven [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) - its latest version has netstandard2.0 build.

For PDF exports most flexible solution is to generate HTML and then convert it to PDF with tools like wkhtmltopdf or phantomjs - for these ones you can use C# wrappers that provide simple .NET API.

For DOCX export you can use [OpenXml SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), however it offers rather low-level API. Maybe it is good idea to prepare DOCX "templates", and fill them with real data when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //create stream
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();                         
           using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
                {
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                    // Create the document structure.  
                    mainPart.Document = new Document();
                    Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                    Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                    Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                    run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello, World!"));

                     mainPart.Document.Save();
                     wordDocument.Close();

                   mem.Position = 0;                
                       
                }
           return File(mem, "application/msword", "Sample.docx");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).